# Twilio - Recording an INCOMING Call

Tags: twilio

I'm currently building a phone tree.  Each time a user calls, the entire call needs to be recorded for liability reasons.

Twilio seems to support two ways of recording a call,

1) The  verb, which cannot be nested in other verbs, and cannot have other verbs nested within it.  This means I cannot use this to record any speech as the user navigates the phone tree.
2) The Dial verb, which requires a valid number to dial.  I cannot provide a valid number to dial, as I do not want to call anybody - I want the user who called me to be recorded.

The obvious solution here is to make two numbers, where the first one simply calls the second number with the  verb.  However, with this solution, I would be paying for two incoming calls and one outgoing call for each minute a user calls.  With the volume we typically get, this is totally unrealistic.

Is there any way to simply record incoming calls?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the rest of the call that you are recording do? Could you `<Dial>` into a `<Conference>` which was recorded and have a bot (effectively) dial in to it to perform the other side of the call?

Comment: _I cannot provide a valid number to dial, as I do not want to call anybody - I want the user who called me to be recorded._ Caller phones up and is connected to Twilio. Caller chooses phone tree option to talk to you. Twilio now has to call your phone in order to connect you to the caller, you record that call.

Comment: The caller does not use the phone tree option to talk to me - the caller spends 100% of their time navigating the phone tree, which should be recorded, then hangs up.